# Visual force page - SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

Tags: validation, visualforce

I have a very basic question, regarding I believe **addFields**.
Typically I would take the time to learn by reading around and testing how that works but I have just deployed my first page ever into my org's prod and it seems that the validations around that delete button are too restrictive.

As you may imagine it is now an emergency, what I am trying to do is allow the person who created the custom object to Delete it (the object Review_Error__c is also a junction object). Here is the code I want to add:  "|| **$User.Id = Review_Error__c.Creator_of_Error__c"** (CreatedByID would be even better)

From what I understand I should call the field that needs to be evaluated but I simply don't know how, just keep breaking the all thing. Thank you in advance, and sorry 'bout that!

```
<apex:page action="{!if($User.ProfileId ='00ew0000001IEGkAAO' 
                || $User.ProfileId ='00ew00000015rLxAAI' 
                || $User.ProfileId ='00ew00000015rThAAI'
                || $User.ProfileId ='00ew0000001h4mMAAQ'
                || $UserRole.Id ='00Ew0000000pgDYEAY' 
                || $User.Id = Review_Error__c.Creator_of_Error__c,        
urlFor($Action.Review_Error__c.Delete, $CurrentPage.Parameters.id, [retURL='/a04'], true),
null    
)
}"
  standardController="Review_Error__c">
 <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:PageMessage summary="You are not allowed to delete Review Errors. May you have any question please contact your administrator."
        severity="Warning"
        strength="3"/>
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The final working code:

```
<apex:page action="{!if($User.ProfileId ='00ew0000001IEGkAAO' 
                || $User.ProfileId ='00ew00000015rLxAAI' 
                || $User.ProfileId ='00ew00000015rThAAI'
                || $User.ProfileId ='00ew0000001h4mMAAQ'
                || $UserRole.Id ='00Ew0000000pgDYEAY' 
                || $User.Id = Review_Error__c.CreatedById,         
urlFor($Action.Review_Error__c.Delete, $CurrentPage.Parameters.id, [retURL='/a04'], true),
null    
)
}"
standardController="Review_Error__c"> 
  <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!Review_Error__c.CreatedById}" />
    <apex:PageMessage summary="You are not allowed to delete Review Errors. May you have any question please contact your administrator."
        severity="Warning"
        strength="3"/>
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your page.

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Review_Error__c.Creator_of_Error__c}" />
```

The reason I have put it as `inputHidden` is that it wont show up on the page, but if you want to you could use inputField, outputField, outputText etc..

This should get that field in the context and you should be able to evaluate it.

Alternatively you can do the same from the controller

```
public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        List<String> fields = new List<String>();
        fields.add('Creator_of_Error__c');
        stdController.addFields(fields);

        this.objRec = (Review_Error__c)stdController.getRecord();

}
```

Comment: Just the `<apex:inputHidden value="{!Creator_of_Error__c}" />` on the VF page didnt work for you?

Comment: I still have the same problem, most probably because I don't know where to put that code. Didn't even manage to fir the first one
<apex:page action="{!if($User.ProfileId=
[---]
  standardController="Review_Error__c">  
  public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        List<String> fields = new List</String>();
        fields.add('Creator_of_Error__c');
        stdController.addFields(fields);

        this.objRec = (Review_Error__c)stdController.getRecord();
}
[---]
     <apex:pageBlock>       
        <apex:pageMessages/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

Comment: I get that error  Error: <apex:page> is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1

Comment: That might be because I was trying to add it on the first line? Also i'd be happy using a standard field like Created By Id or something

Comment: Just add the <apex:inputHidden...> immediately after <apex:pageBlock> tag. Don't add anything else. The other code is supposed to be added on the controller side, not on the Vf page.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate that worked, I just had to change a bit the value by adding the object name "value="{!Review_Error__c.CreatedById}"".
Using Apex is awesome but I clearly have a lot to learn! I'd invite you for a beer if I could ;)

Comment: You are welcome @MaximePetit :) And thanks for pointing out the correction. I have updated the answer so that someone else might be benefited.